# XML Prefix Attributes in SOAP Call CRM 2016

Tags: xml, soap, dynamics-crm

I am making a SOAP Call to CRM 2016 Organization via SOAPUI. Following is the working call:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
<Execute xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <request i:type="a:CreateRequest" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
    <a:Parameters xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
      <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
        <b:key>Target</b:key>
        <b:value i:type="a:Entity">
          <a:Attributes>
            <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
              <b:key>subject</b:key>
              <b:value i:type="c:string" xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">SOAP UI Task</b:value>
            </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
              <b:key>description</b:key>
              <b:value i:type="c:string" xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">This is a test task created by SOAP UI.</b:value>
            </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
              <b:key>regardingobjectid</b:key>
              <b:value i:type="a:EntityReference">
                <a:Id>10A25151-5331-E711-80D0-000C2995F954</a:Id>
                <a:LogicalName>test_salesorder</a:LogicalName>
                <a:Name i:nil="true" />
              </b:value>
            </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
              <b:key>test_tasktype</b:key>
              <b:value i:type="a:OptionSetValue">
                <a:Value>970390000</a:Value>
              </b:value>
            </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
          </a:Attributes>
          <a:EntityState i:nil="true" />
          <a:FormattedValues />
          <a:Id>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</a:Id>
          <a:LogicalName>test_ordertask</a:LogicalName>
          <a:RelatedEntities />
        </b:value>
      </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
    </a:Parameters>
    <a:RequestId i:nil="true" />
    <a:RequestName>Create</a:RequestName>
  </request>
</Execute>
```

Changing

```
<a:EntityState i:nil="true" /> 
to 
<a:EntityState nil="true" />
```

is giving me a Formatter exception, I am not sure why making it in no namespace is giving exception? Is it mandatory to give prefix/namespace?

WSDL https://www.dropbox.com/s/1v7o7ol38jhd434/WSDL.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case it is mandatory. Attributes, just like elements can have namespaces. And the default attribute that you have to set for a nillable element has a namespace, so it needs to be set. If not, this does not conform to the XML Schema Definition and will not validate.

> The nil attribute is defined in the XML Schema instance namespace,
>   http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance (commonly associated with
>   the prefix xsi), and applies only to XML instance documents, not XML
>   Schema documents. A value of true for the xsi:nil attribute in an XML
>   element explicitly specifies that the element has no content, whether
>   child elements or body text.
>
> [Original article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybce7f69(v=vs.100).aspx)